# Probability.. How do I calculate this?

Tags: probability

At a casino, a combination of two spinners is used to decide the winner based on the sum of scores from spinning. The spinners each have four colored spaces - red, yellow, blue, and green. Red = 1, Yellow = 2, Blue = 3, and Green = 4

What is the probability that the spinners land on colors summing up to exactly 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$3 = 1+2$, so you must either get red in the first one, and yellow in the second one, or the opposite. Therefore, you only have two cases.
The probability is :
$$p = \frac{\textrm{Number of favorable cases}}{\textrm{Number of cases possible}} = \frac{2}{4\times4} = \frac{1}{8}$$

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense!